# PSQL just closes after asking for my account password

Tags: postgresql, crash, passwords, psql, psqlodbc

During the PSQL.exe launch I am asked for my account password. After providing the password the tool just closes with no error message or indication of what went wrong. 
My account has full admin privileges and regardless of if I run the tool with Admin Privileges or normally the result is always the same.
I am using PostgreSQL 11.5 and PSQLODBC 12.0.

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: Have a look at the PostgreSQL log.